# How to achieve Elasticsearch aggregation by grids of specific size?

Tags: elasticsearch, geolocation, kibana, geojson, elasticsearch-aggregation

Basically, what I have is a polygon that I use to filter my data through a Geoshape query. What I would like to achieve is to apply an Elasticsearch aggregation to that query that gives me a bucket for every grid of an specific size, for example, 1km, inside that polygon.

Of course, the aggregation is done over a Geopoint type field.

I've tried the [Geohash aggregation grid](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-shape-query.html#query-dsl-geo-shape-query), because it allows me to specify a precision of "1km". But results don't always have the exact form of a grid, it is just an aproximation.

Here's my current query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "timestamp": {
                    "gte": 1662012000000,
                    "lte": 1662098399999
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "filter": {
              "geo_shape": {
                "location": {
                  "shape": {
                    "type": "polygon",
                    "coordinates": [
                      [
                        [
                          -84.5214136675492,
                          9.911814727700381
                        ],
                        [
                          -85.02380959494664,
                          10.897883119232858
                        ],
                        [
                          -85.02380959494664,
                          10.90692961823774
                        ],
                        ....
                      ]
                    ]
                  },
                  "relation": "WITHIN"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "_source": true,
  "sort": [
    {
      "timestamp": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],"aggs": {
    "1km-grids": {
      "geohash_grid": {
        "field": "location",
        "precision": "1km"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sales": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "finales.tiempo_mdev"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to achive what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Geotile grid aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-geotilegrid-aggregation.html) to bucket data by web mercator grid. The advantage of geotile grid vs geohash grid is that geotile grid will always be square. Set `precision` parameter to specify the grid size. See https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/zoom-level/#zoom-levels-and-geographical-distance for details about how zoom levels correlate to grid size.